# How to fix an image texture to object and camera?

Tags: texturing, camera, coordinates

I've looked for a similar problem but couldn't find anywhere, so here it goes.

I'm having an issue with fixing the position of this image in the body of the sphere, as you can see, it leaves the position as I pan the view. I need it to be fixed as the object moves and faces the camera at all angles.

[image]

[image]

Here are the node config I used, I'm absolute beginner on this so take it easy on me.

[image]

Thanks everyone who wish to help ;)

Comment: Don't use the camera coordinates use UVs. And read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Comment: Once you create the texture properly with UVs, then add a track to constraint on the object, so that it rotates with the camera, so that is always facing the lens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, susu. Also the link you sent is very, very helpful! Is there a way to make the texture look flat? Because it gets distorted with the curvature of the sphere, if it doesn't it's ok the way it is.